# Correct way to handle duplicate UDP DNS Requests?

Tags: dns, udp

I am playing with writing my own DNS Server.
I notice that I get duplicate requests on UDP (same question domain and same txid)

This is on a my own private network. I test it by loading up 20ish tabs in chromes.
I only usually see 2-3 duplicates for a given packet (if any).

What is the correct way to handle these requests? Drop them or send back duplicate responses?
Is this just UDP unreliability? Or do clients (if my server is too slow) retry with the same txid?

Comment: As far as I can recall the DNS RFCs are silent on the question of whether repeated queries should re-use the original query ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Chrome retrying because it didn't get a reply from you within its timeout period, which used to be 6 seconds a couple of years ago but may have changed since then (the chromium source is available to review online and is quite easy to read).

You should always send back a duplicate answer from your recent cache in case the reason for retry is an actual dropped packet - highly unlikely on your local net but I'm assuming you want to write a resiliant server.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just one or two duplicates, they may well be because the first response UDP packet got lost on the way to the questioner, and the reasonable thing would be to resend. If it's hundreds of duplicates it's probably someone trying to use you for an amplification attack, and you should really not resend.

Comment: Edited question, its on a private network. I only see 2-3 duplicates under load.